# judge the values crossing zero

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to determine whether or not the ranges of min and max values cross zero (`0 = crossing zero, 1 = not crossing zero`).

```
min <- c(0, -1, -1, 1, 1)
max <- c(1, 1, -0.1, 3, 1.5)
answer <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
data <- cbind(min,max, answer)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the between function from dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
min <- c(0, -1, -1, 1, 1)
max <- c(1, 1, -0.1, 3, 1.5)
df1 = data.frame(min,max) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(answer = as.numeric(!between(0,min,max)))
```

Or using base R:

```
df1 = data.frame(min,max)
df1$answer = apply(df1, 1, function(x) as.numeric(!(x[1]<= 0 & x[2] >=0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R vectorised answer -

```
transform(data, answer = as.integer(!(min <= 0 & max > 0)))

#  min  max answer
#1   0  1.0      0
#2  -1  1.0      0
#3  -1 -0.1      1
#4   1  3.0      1
#5   1  1.5      1
```

If you prefer `dplyr` the same can be written as -

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate(answer = as.integer(!(min <= 0 & max > 0)))
```

**data**

```
min <- c(0, -1, -1, 1, 1)
max <- c(1, 1, -0.1, 3, 1.5)
data <- data.frame(min,max)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply multiply them, as to cross you either need a negative product or one being zero.

```
answer <- ifelse(min * max <= 0, 0, 1)
```

or

```
answer <- as.integer(min * max > 0)

# [1] 0 0 1 1 1
```

If your 0 and 1 are not a requirement, even shorter to get a TRUE or FALSE

```
answer <- min * max <= 0
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: A shorter one might be `answer <- +(min * max >0)`

Comment: nice, I did not know that one to convert a TRUE / FALSE to 1 / 0